# Memory leaks testing

Tags: c++, stl, instruments, memory-leaks

I'm doing memory leaks testing for our product with Instruments.

`std:string` or `std::auto_ptr` objects are detected leaks. As I know, these two kinds of objects will release themselves. I'm wondering they are really leaks or just because I stopped recording too early and Instruments didn't detect they are released?

Is Instruments accurate on these kinds of objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can leak a `std::string` object and that is not too hard:

```
int main(){
  std::string* s = new std::string();
  return 0;
}
```

Same way you can leak an `auto_ptr`. A std::string will release the dynamically allocated string array it contains but it will not `release itself`.